# Performance and impact to schedule different cachenames

Tags: performance, api, spring-boot, scheduler

I have an API based on a spring boot app that caches different methods with different time delay,

```
@Cacheable(value = "findAllByIdType", key="#p0")
List<NomenclatureEntity> findAllByIdType(String type);

@Cacheable(value = "findByIdTypeAndIdKey", key="#p0 + #p1")
NomenclatureEntity findByIdTypeAndIdKey(String type,String key);
```

Cache Config :

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnExpression("${cache.enable:true}")
@EnableCaching
@EnableScheduling
public class CacheConfig {
    private static final String findByIdTypeAndIdKey = "findByIdTypeAndIdKey";
    private static final String findAllByIdType = "findAllByIdType";
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CacheConfig.class);


      @Bean
      public CacheManager cacheManager() {
          ConcurrentMapCacheManager cacheManager = new ConcurrentMapCacheManager(findByIdTypeAndIdKey,findAllByIdType);

          return cacheManager;
      }

    @CacheEvict(allEntries = true, value = {findByIdTypeAndIdKey})
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay =  24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ,  initialDelay = 500)
    public void reportCacheEvict() {
        LOGGER.debug("## Flush Data Cache findByIdTypeAndIdKey");
    }


    @CacheEvict(allEntries = true, value = {findAllByIdType})
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay =  24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ,  initialDelay = 500)
    public void reportCacheEvict2() {
        LOGGER.debug("## Flush Data Cache findAllByIdType");
    }

}
```

The app works perfeclyt but my doubt is about **performance**, its a good way (practice) to do like that or there's a better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the size of your application.

```
ConcurrentMapCacheManager
```

As its name indicates you use a `Map` to cache your data so your Heap's memory will grow up as same as your cache. This is suitable during development but for production consider using other types of cache like `Redis`. 
For cache eviction, you can control it as you did or rely on cache provider to evict data when the allocated memory is reached (by default Redis use `LRU (Least Recently Used)`  algorithm to evict data).

Comment: Thanks @akuma8 for that i've configured HazelCast to my application